# Gremlin repeat operations from same start point

Tags: gremlin

### Objective

I want to generate random walks in Gremlin, and already have the command to generate one: `g.V(<start_id>).repeat(local(both().sample(1))).times(<depth>).path()`.
While this is good, I do have to generate `<nb_rw_per_node>` random walks per start node, and I'd like to use a unique query to handle it if possible.

### Issue

I've tried using the `repeat()` step, in combination with `select()` to do this, as follows:

```
g.V(<start_id>).as("start").
  repeat(
    select("start").
    repeat(
      local(
        both().sample(1)
      )
    ).times(<depth>).path()
  ).emit().times(<nb_rw_per_node>)
```

This yields the following results, which I don't understand (here, `<depth> = 2` and `<nb_rw_per_nodes> = 2`)

```
gremlin> g.V(6652128).as("start").repeat(select("start").repeat(local(both().sample(1))).times(2).path()).emit().times(2)
==>path[v[6652128], v[6652128], v[95670392], v[1044704]]
==>path[v[6652128], v[6652128], v[95670392], v[1044704], path[v[6652128], v[6652128], v[95670392], v[1044704]], v[6652128], v[94818432], v[245928]]
```

How can I not get the first node doubled in the path?
Why is the second result the concatenation of the first result and the concatenation of the first result and a random walk of the correct length? I expected to get another path of the same format as the first one.

Is this the correct way to generate multiple paths from a same initial node in a single query? If so, how can I correct my query?

Thanks to everyone reading and answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `select` you essentially add another copy of the thing selected to the path. If you need 2 random walks from the same start, why not just include the start twice at the very beginning? So the query becomes something like this (using a data set I have to hand):

```java
gremlin> g.V(44,44).repeat(local(out().sample(1))).times(2).path()

==>[v[44],v[8],v[580]]
==>[v[44],v[20],v[34]]
```

To use nested `repeat` steps you will need something like this:

```java
gremlin> g.V('44').as('s').
......1>   repeat(select('s').as('start').
......2>          repeat(local(out().sample(1))).
......3>          times(4).path().from('start')).
......4>   times(3).
......5>   emit()

==>[v[44],v[31],v[271],v[149],v[4]]
==>[v[44],v[31],v[264],v[1],v[152]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[38],v[4],v[190]]
```

This last option is a little gimmicky, but also works.

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).
......1>   repeat(store('x').identity()).times(3).
......2>   cap('x').
......3>   unfold().as('start').
......4>   repeat(local(out().sample(1))).
......5>   times(2).
......6>   path().
......7>     from('start')

==>[v[44],v[31],v[42]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[407]]
==>[v[44],v[13],v[53]]
```

In each of the last two examples, the real key is the introduction of the `from` step to avoid the redundant starting vertex entries from being included. Try running the queries without the `from` to see the difference.

Comment: Strangely, the method with repetition of the node `g.V(44, 44, 44, ...)...` doesn't yield consistent results. I am requesting 25 random walks to be done (so I put `44` 25 times), yet it only returns 20 to 23 paths. I don't understand why it isn't constant and why it isn't equal to 25.